# Handling arbitrary text blocks in an Xtext grammar

Tags: xtext

In an effort to better understand Xtext, I'm working on writing a grammar and have hit a roadblock.  I've boiled it down to the following scenario.  I have some input such as this:

```
thing {abc}
{def}
```

There may be keywords (e.g.'thing') followed by other language elements (e.g. ID) in braces.  Or, there can just be a block of content inside braces.  This content should simply be passed along to the parser en masse.

If I try something like this:

```
Model: (things+=AThing | blocks+=ABlock)*;

AThing : 'thing' '{' name = ID '}';

ABlock : block=BLOCK;

terminal BLOCK:'{' -> '}';
```

and parse the sample text above, I get an error:

```
'mismatched input '{abc}' expecting '{'' on ABlock, offset 6, length 5
```

So, '{abc}' is being matched by the BLOCK terminal rule, which I understand.  But how do I alter the grammar to properly handle the sample input?  I've been wrestling with this problem for a while and have come up empty.  So it's either something very simple that I've missed, or the problem is really complex and I don't realize it.  Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing happens in two stages: tokenizer and lexical. In the first one the text input is divided into tokens, in the second one the tokens are matched against lexical rules. Broadly something like (with some arbitrary language):

1st phase:

```
text:    class  X   {   this  ;   }
         ----- --- ---  ---- --- ---
tokens:   ID   ID  LB  ID    SC  RB
```

2nd phase:

Is there a rule that starts with a 'class' string?

```
YES: Is the next expected token an ID?
  YES: Is the next expected token a LB?
    ...
  NO: Is there another rule that starts with 'class'?
    ...
NO: Is there a rule that starts with an ID token?
  ...
```

The lexer implementation is a bit more complex, but I hope you get the idea.

The issue with your grammar is that your termial BLOCK rule is used during the first phase, hence you get

```
thing {abc} {def}
----- ----- -----
ID    BLOCK BLOCK
```

That is why the error message says if found '{abc}' and not a '{'. The lexer matched the thing and was expecting the next token to be a '{' but it got a BLOCK. 
If you want arbitrary text inside the block, I don't think you can use '{' to identify the name of things.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what is mentioned [here](https://dslmeinte.wordpress.com/2014/08/26/resolving-ambiguities-in-xtext-grammars-without-backtracking-part-1/):

> A quite common case requiring backtracking is when your language uses the same delimiter pair for two different semantics

So the simplest solution seems to use different delimiters. Otherwise you may have to look into enabling backtracking.